# Can I use a Mac Pro for my office and run Parallels for my Windows-based ERP software?

Tags: hardware-recommendation

I have a small business that runs a Windows-based network.  I'm wondering if I can set up a Mac Pro, with virtual servers, and use Parallels for my ERP software?  Basically, can I have a Mac-based server and still run my business software?

Comment: Patrix, yes, sorry about that.  I'm new, still trying to get this down.  See my edit above, hopefully that is clearer.

Comment: Much clearer, thought so anyway. Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Both Parallels or VMware Fusion will work for you.

My personal preference is for VMware.